# Prefetch flag in RMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

If the prefetch count is set to 100 and there are multiple consumers listening to rmq .The function in consumer is inserting in table .Is it possible that we can have duplicate entries in that table because of prefetch in any scenario